# get transaction hash web3 and ether

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, react

On my website you can pay with ETH, but I want to get the transaction hash, how can I do that? I'm using web3 and ether on my react app This is how I initialize the transaction

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(e.target);
        setError();
        await startPayment({
        setError,
        setTxs,
        ether: data.get("ether"),
        addr: myWalletId
        });
    };
```

This is the startPayment func

```
const startPayment = async ({ setError, setTxs, ether, addr }) => {
    try {
      if (!window.ethereum)
        throw new Error("No crypto wallet found. Please install it.");
  
      await window.ethereum.send("eth_requestAccounts");
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      ethers.utils.getAddress(addr);
      const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
        to: addr,
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ether),
      });
      setTxs([tx]);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  };
```

SOLVED

I used a simple console log to get it

```
console.log(`Transaction hash: ${tx.hash}`);
```

Comment: you need to share the code of `startPayment()` to get a good answer. Meanwhile, answer can be found in documentation: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/transactions/

Comment: @KyleBaker sorry, now is updated

Comment: You should put it as an answer (even though it is your own question) and accept it, to help future users.